# How to change the text of a button after switching pages with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a site that has buttons on the menu, Buy in person and another Buy Online, what I want to happen is that when the person clicks on one of the buttons for example Buy Online, the user goes to the Buy page but the text of the button must be changed from Buy Online to Online same as Buy In Person button when clicked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: when you visit a new url, a new page will be loaded from scratch. Changing the text of a button you just clicked to visit another url, is pretty unclear to grasp in terms of expectations. You should include more details like what did you do so far to get there?

Comment: @DiegoD So I couldn't find a way, I still thought of comparing the urls and then changing the buttons, you know?

Comment: it's hard to tell because there are not enough details to understand the context.. by the way talking in general, there are some ways to pass data while navigating from page to page... the easiest approach coming to my mind would be to use a get parameter when visiting the next page that would be checked by its js code and used as a condition to change that button text.. if you agree with this solution I could show you an example in an answer

Answer (score 0):

As I first suggested in the comments, one way to achieve that result, could be to use a get parameter as the signal to instruct the page to change the button text you are talking about.

So that when you visit the url normally, the button text doesn't change and remains `Buy Online`, but when the url is visited with the parameter that we arbitrarily chose to be `?q=1`, the code running when the page is loaded will change the button text to `Online`.

I used `window.location.search` to get the query string coming from the currently visited url:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search

That code will behave differently only if the page was visited as `https://host/path/to/the/page?q=1` (and that's how you should reference that page from the first button pointing there)

```js
//adds code to run when the page is ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  
  /**
   * Here it grabs the query string following the url you are visiting
   * Since in this demo frame it won't work, I commented that line
   * and statically populated the queryString variable with a string literal
   */
  //const queryString = window.location.search;
  const queryString = '?q=1';
  
  const params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  const q = parseInt(params.get("q")); // is the number 1

  if(q == '1'){
    document.getElementById('buyonline').innerText = 'Online';
  }
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="buyonline">Buy Online</button>
```